# IE8 rendering on each keystroke in textarea gets slower as page size expands

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8

I have a page using JQuery and I've implemented infinite scrolling on a div. There is a text area on the page. I've noticed that as more rows get added to a table in the scrollable div performance of the page gets worse. You can really tell when the page size is large and you try to type anything in the text area because there is a large lag between the time text is typed into the textarea and the time that you actually see the text appear. This only happens in IE8. I haven't tried other IE versions. It doesn't happen in Firefox. It is really fast in Firefox.

I've used a tool to check what IE was doing and it is spending most of the time doing generic rendering of the page for each key stroke even though nothing new is being added to the page.

Why is the page rendering so often and slowly in IE8 and is there a way to improve this?

Comment: This does *not* belong on *superuser.com*, it's just fine here.

Comment: Ie is so bad for javascript its incredible. That being said I guess you should post some code if you want more precise help.

Comment: Is it possible that in your routine you create a new object everytime you add a row and it gets added? IE having bad performance could show a problem thats always there faster then the more performant browsers.

Comment: Does IE's memory usage keep going up while you're doing this? Maybe you've got a memory leak or are leaving dead nodes in the DOM? Firefox's javascript is a couple of orders of magnitude faster/better than IE, so if you're testing in FF, test with 10x as much data and see if it slows down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the **tables** are the cause of your performance issues. I had similar problems when using js to dynamically add rows to a table containing form elements.

See this [Microsoft Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533020%28VS.85%29.aspx#Use_Fixed-Size_Tables) for tips on how to improve performance, specifically when using tables.

- Set the table-layout CSS attribute to fixed on the table.
- Explicitly define col objects for each column.
- Set the WIDTH attribute on each col.

e.g.:

```
table
 {
 table-layout:fixed;
 }
```

Avoid nesting tables within tables etc.

[W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_tab_table-layout.asp) highlights the advantages and disadvantages to using different table layout algorithms.

FireFox appears to handle the rendering of tables more efficiently than IE but using these techniques appears to help most browsers.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

A similar problem can occur with lag on text areas in IE8 for very large pages. It does seem to be a problem with IE8 rendering the page on every key press.

One solution is to use an iframe with contentEditable set to true instead of a textarea. This works without any noticeable lag at all on the same page. I suspect this is because IE8 is only rendering the contents of the iframe on each keypress and not the parent document. It may also work with a textarea inside an iframe but I haven't tried this.